# SQL query throws a date error ("day of month must be between 1 and last day of month")

Tags: sql, database, create-table

I am trying to execute below keep getting the message that the day of month must be between 1 and last day of - month

I get an error for the date

> Day of month must be between 1 and last day of month

Code:

```
create table haias.atpbos48172_BOS_personer_2020 as
    select distinct(bg.personnummer) 
    from bos.bg_person bg
    inner join bos.sagspart sp on 1 = 1
                               and sp.person_id = bg.person_id
                               and sp.relationsrolle = 'PRIMAERPART'
                               and sp.gyldig_fra <= to_timestamp('2020-12-31','YYYY-MM-DD')
                               and (nvl(sp.gyldig_til, '9999-12-31') > to_timestamp('2020-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'))
    inner join bos.sag s on 1 = 1
                         and s.id = sp.sag_id
                         and s.gyldig_fra <= to_timestamp('2020-12-31','YYYY-MM-DD')
                         and (nvl(s.gyldig_til, '9999-12-31') > to_timestamp('2020-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'))
                         and s.brugervendt_noegle like 'BO%'
    inner join bos.bs_sag bs on 1 = 1
                             and bs.sag_id = s.id
    inner join bos.bs_sag_detaljer bsd on 1 = 1
                                       and bsd.bs_sag_id = bs.id
                                       and (bsd.sagstype like '1%' or bsd.sagstype like '6%') --Statustyper der identificerer sagen som en BOS-sag
                                       and bsd.statuskode in ('01', '02', '03', '04', '17')
                                       and bsd.gyldig_fra <= to_timestamp('2020-12-31','YYYY-MM-DD')
                                       and (nvl(bsd.gyldig_til, '9999-12-31') > to_timestamp('2020-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'))
    inner join bos.afgoerelse a on 1 = 1
                                and a.sag_id = s.id
                                and (a.type <> 'AFSLAG' or a.afslagsaarsag = 'BEREGNINGSMAESSIGT_AFSLAG')
                                and a.gyldig_fra <= to_timestamp('2020-12-31','YYYY-MM-DD')
                                and (nvl(a.gyldig_til, '9999-12-31') > to_timestamp('2020-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

Comment: Please tag with the specific RDBMS you are using (Oracle, MySql etc)

Comment: `distinct` is not a function, it's _set quantifier_, and a part of `select distinct` - which returns distinct _rows_. Remove those extra parentheses and simply write `select distinct bg.personnummer from...`, to make code clearer.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm, e.g. start over and then add one join at the time.